# Android application with more than 100 MB preloaded sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, size, limit, apk

we are developing an android application for a survey. During the survey the enumerators check people against a preloaded sqlite database. Size of the preloaded database is likey to be more than 100 MB. Given the size limit of 50 MB for android apk, what should be the approach to deploy the database along with the application. The application would be loaded into the device using USB and then handed over to the enumerators.

Comment: pre-loaded 100MB database is a bad idea from the start. you should probably be connecting to a REST service, to check for the data, instead of a pre-loaded database.

Comment: Try putting the database content into a file or multiple files in SD card .When you require to access the data ,fetch the file ,parse it and use it OR you can use a webservice.

Comment: This idea seems good -'Create a webservice. Have your application call the webservice which in turn downloads the database to your Android device' available here . Is there any limit of the database I can download from WebServices. In that case data can be loaded into the device at the distribution center before handing over it to the enumerators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think the problem is solved. I am copying the db onto the SDCard and on start of application copying it to the \data\data\mypackagename\databases directory. On the next start it checks whether DB exists and does nothing. It is working fine. thanks for the suggestions.